# ActiveRecord joins on aggregate query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Unit` model that `has_many :transacions`.  Transaction has a `type` column that indicates what kind fo transaction it is: sale, transfer, reservation, etc.

I would like to find all units that have a given transaction type as their latest transaction.  I can't figure out how to do it in ActiveRecord.

In SQL, if for example I wanted to find all units with "Transfer" as their latest transaction I could do:

```
SELECT u.*, tx.* FROM units u INNER JOIN transactions tx ON u.id=tx.unit_id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT tx.unit_id, max(tx.created_at) AS latest_tx_date
  FROM transactions tx
  GROUP BY tx.unit_id
  ORDER BY tx.unit_id
) max_dates
ON (tx.unit_id=max_dates.unit_id AND tx.created_at>=max_dates.latest_tx_date)
WHERE tx.type='Transfer';
```

It's the joining with the inner query that I'm having trouble with.  Is there a readable ActiveRecord way to do this or should I just use the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord supports [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html). No need to write plain SQL.

Comment: Yes, I am using single-table inheritance.  Hence the `type` column on the `transactions` table.

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do.  Using `sale` as an example I am not trying to get the latest `sale` transaction.  I am trying to get the units whose latest transaction is a 'sale` and not another type.