# Rails scope with multiple joins and record finding

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, scope, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Client, Deal and DealType models. 
Client has many deals. Deal belongs to DealType. DealType has property — closing.
I need to select all clients, that have not closed deals.

Something like `scope :active, -> { where('deals.last.deal_type.closing = ?', false) }` (it's, of course, incorrect).

How can I do it in best way in Rails 4?

ps. Will be grateful for links to sources for understanding sql queries with rails.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
joins(deals: :deal_type).where('deal_types.closing = ?', false)
```

A good read:

[ActiveRecord Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying)

In particular:

[Joining Tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Comment: Thanks. It's almost that I want, but I need to check only last (by id or date) deal of client :)

Comment: Ah, your requirement is similar to mine.  I did it by using SQL, haven't found an ActiveRecord way to do it.  Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709552/activerecord-joins-on-aggregate-query

Comment: Adding to @jcm. I could not find a complete active record solution. But we could do this:

    `scope: :active, -> {joins(deals: :deal_type).joins("INNER JOIN (SELECT deals.client_id, MAX(deals.created_at)
     AS latest_deals_date FROM deals GROUP BY deals.client_id) latest_deals ON 
     (deals.client_id=latest_deals.client_id AND      deals.created_at>=latest_deals.latest_deals_date)").where('deal_types.closing = ?', false)}`

Comment: @Abhinaya yes, it looks like that inner query really needs to be done in SQL.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind doing it in raw SQL try:

```
SELECT clients.*,deals.* FROM clients INNER JOIN deals ON clients.id=deals.client_id
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT deals.client_id, MAX(deals.created_at) AS latest_deals_date
 FROM deals
 GROUP BY deals.client_id
) latest_deals
ON (deals.client_id=latest_deals.client_id AND deals.created_at>=latest_deals.latest_deals_date)
INNER JOIN deal_types ON deals.deal_type_id=deal_types.id
WHERE deal_types.closing=false;
```